# bootstrap select menu validation working in firefox but not in chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, bootstrap-4

I am working on a project which is related to HTML forms. I am using bootstrap to validate the form but I may have run into a problem. When I had added a select menu to the form and I tested the form validation, The other input fields showed the validation styles on the select menu in firefox only. Not in chrome or edge. Check the screenshots below:

Firefox:

[image]

Chrome:

[image]

In the images, it clearly shows that the select menu validation only works for Firefox but not in chrome.
I have also mentioned a code snippet below: (Try running the snippet in firefox)

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 mx-auto mt-5">
            <form action="?" method="POST" class="was-validated" novalidate="">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="mySelect" class="custom-select" required="">
                        <option disabled="" selected="" hidden="">Choose</option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <p class="invalid-feedback">You must choose an option</p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

So, my questions are:

1. Is there a way to make bootstrap select validation work for chrome also?
2. Is there something I am missing here?

Comment: In Chrome `required` causes a notification only if you press submit button (try to submit the empty value). Also required can't be set with value so instead of `required=""` type just `required` before `>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `value` attribute for shows error. chrome detect `empty` string in value and shows valid input, for that in chrome you need to use `value` attribute without specifying a value.

Please Use `required` not `required=''`, there is no problem with `required=''` but `required` is industrial choice.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7 mx-auto mt-5">
            <form action="?" method="POST" class="was-validated" novalidate>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <select name="mySelect" class="custom-select" required>
                        <option disabled selected hidden value>Choose</option>
                        <option value="1">Option 1</option>
                        <option value="2">Option 2</option>
                    </select>
                    <p class="invalid-feedback">You must choose an option</p>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary mt-3">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: But i have one question, What if we had the same code in an `XHTML` Document? `XHTML` requires attribute values to be quoted right?

Comment: try `value=""` instead

Comment: If you like my answer or you got any help from my answer, don't forget to consider up-vote